# Rewrite relation in second normal form

Tags: database-normalization

I have the following relation:

```
Theater = (theaterID, viewerID, viewerAge, room)
```

theaterID and viewerID are the primary keys.

I know that it is not in second normal form because viewerAge is functionally dependent on viewerID which is only part of the primary key.

My question is how would I rewrite this relation in 2NF?

Comment: This can't be answered since you didn't give a cover for the FDs that hold. Also 2NF does not involve PKs, it involves CKs. "heaterID and viewerID are the primary keys." does not make sense because there can only be one PK; from what you write later, you seem to mean the PK is {heaterID and viewerID}. "because viewerAge is functionally dependent on viewerID which is only part of the primary key" is not enough, you must say that it is also a non-prime attribute.

Comment: Once you give your assignment correctly, this will be too broad. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please show & justify the steps of your work following a published academic textbook & ask a specific question where stuck. Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Neverthess: This is a faq. There are many questions on how to normalize to 2NF.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do:

Theater = (theaterID, viewerID, room) 
Viewer = (viewerID, viewerAge)

Note the following two things though:

1. Stackoverflow is not a mechanical (crowd-source) version of "Hey Google" or "Siri". If it is your homework/assignment, ask your professor or your tutor.
2. Having said that, you may need to create two tables because each relation becomes a table in an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Leave only theater ID as a primary key?